# undescore _.each and grunt

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, underscore.js

I get warning from Grunt when I use underscore library:

```
let userId = 502;
let member = _.find($scope.data.userReports, function (member) {
     return member.person.id === userId;
});
```

Don't make functions within a loop.

When I try correct this situation I doesn't get member from underscore (is undefined, but also member is not passed into checkUserFunction).

```
let userId = 502;
var member = _.find($scope.data.userReports, checkUserFunction(member, userId));

let checkUserFunction = (member, dataKey) => {
    if(parseInt(member.person.id) === parseInt(dataKey)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is that you're calling find like this:

```
_.find($scope.data.userReports, checkUserFunction(member, userId));
```

When you should be calling it like this:

```
_.find($scope.data.userReports, checkUserFunction);
```

By including the braces when you pass in checkUserFunction you're not passing the function, you're passing in the *return* value of the function.
Also, the predicate for find only accepts one parameter so I think what you need is more like this:

```
let userId = 502;
var member = _.find($scope.data.userReports, checkUserFunction);

let checkUserFunction = (member) => {
    return parseInt(member.person.id) === userId;
};
```

Comment: No Problem. Happy to help :)